# JNI setting Static Field String Array

Tags: arrays, string, static, java-native-interface

I am trying to set a String Array field in my class but am running into all sorts of problems.  This is what i have so far:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java__Names1_GetMyNames(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
jfieldID myNamesID; /* store the field ID */
int i=0;
jstring myStr;
jobject dev;
char* myNames[] = {"Hello ", "world!"};

// Get a reference to obj’s class 
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
// Get static field ID
myNamesID = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls, "myDevNames", "[Ljava/lang/String;");
// Get the object field
dev = env->GetObjectField(obj,myNamesID);

for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
myStr = env->NewStringUTF(myNames[i]);
env->SetObjectArrayElement(dev,i,myStr);
}
return 0;
}
```

and this is my string:

```
private static String[] myDevNames= new String[12];
```

When i try to compile i get the following error:

error: invalid conversion from 'jobject {aka _jobject*}' to 'jobjectArray {aka _jobjectArray*}' [-fpermissive]

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update - my previous recommendation to use jarray instead of jobject was incorrect.  I was looking at old documentation.  Based on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html how about this?  Redefine dev as jobjectArray, but you also need to do a cast on the call to GetStaticObjectField.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java__Names1_GetMyNames(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
jfieldID myNamesID; /* store the field ID */
int i=0;
jstring myStr;
jobjectArray dev;
char* myNames[] = {"Hello ", "world!"};

// Get a reference to obj’s class 
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
// Get static field ID
myNamesID = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls, "myDevNames", "[Ljava/lang/String;");
// Get the object field
dev = static_cast<jobjectArray>(env->GetStaticObjectField(cls,myNamesID));

for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
myStr = env->NewStringUTF(myNames[i]);
env->SetObjectArrayElement(dev,i,myStr);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changing jobject  dev to jobjectArray or jarray still gives me the compile error: error: invalid conversion from 'jobject {aka _jobject*}' to 'jobjectArray {aka _jobjectArray*}' [-fpermissive]

Comment: ok now it compiles but crashes as soon as i run it. the exception is EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005957cdd0, pid=11632, tid=12036

Comment: Ok it looks like when i change my field from static to instance and use  GetFieldID it works.  When i use a static field it crashes.  Any ideas why?  Thanks for the help so far its greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll take a look. I need to set up a test environment.

Comment: Doh! When you use GetStaticFieldID you must use GetStaticObjectField

Comment: @user1637425 Well if it worked then give him some credit! Up-vote and accept the answer is the least you could do! I'll upvote.